# Show that the following set of six matrices is a group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

> Show that the following set of six matrices is a group
>   $$\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0\\0 & 1\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1\\-1 & -1\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}-1 & -1\\1 & 0\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0\\-1 & -1\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}-1 & -1\\0 & 1\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1\\1 & 0\end{bmatrix}.$$

The only property that is not immediately apparent is closure. The question before this one involved the symmetric group $S_3$ and based off another post, I believe this to be necessary for this question. However, I am not really sure how to make the connection. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please see:[group of 2\times 2 invertible matrices is isomorphic to S_3](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/487225/show-that-the-group-of-2-times-2-invertible-matrices-is-isomorphic-to-s-3?rq=1)

Comment: Take your second matrix, call it A, and multiply it by itself. Then multiply the product by A. Then you should see the pattern and how it relates to the symmetric group.

Comment: @Mike Ok, so the result was the identity matrix. However, I am still unsure of how to use this information. Could you elaborate a little more?

Comment: Well, Suppose we label, from left to right, as I, A, B, C, D, E.  It seems you found that $A^3 = I$.  So $A$ has order $3$, Similarly, $E^2 = I$, so $E$ has order $2$.  What do you know about the orders of elements in $S_3$?

Comment: @amWhy The order of the elements of $S_3$ are 2 and 3, right? My book doesn't go very deep about this, so I'm not to familiar with this stuff.

Comment: Yes indeed, except, of course the identity permutation, which like the Identity matrix here, has order 1.

Comment: Note also, that $B^2 = A,$ and $B^3 = I$, So B has order $3$.

Comment: $C, D$ each have order $2$

Comment: Do you know that any group of order $6$ is isomorphic to either $\mathbb Z_6$ or else to $S_3$?  $Z_6$ under addition modulo 6, is cyclic, and therefor contains an element of order $6$ (the generator).

Comment: $S_3 = \{(1), (12), (23), (13), (123), (132)\}$, and like your group, is not abelian.

Comment: After you have convinced yourself that this is indeed a cyclic group you can state that it is closed since for any matrix $A$ in the group, $A^{-1}$ is in the group. The only way to rigorously prove* that is to do all the multiplications, which I agree is unreasonable. *Since it is a finite collection of objects you would normally just test each one but since this is so tedious I think you can just state it. In $\Bbb{Z_{3}}$ for instance it is quick and easy to test.

Comment: @colj86 For a great lecture series on youtube, look up Matthew Salomone's channel. He goes fast but his videos are crammed with knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the least tedious way is to show we have some identification (I am speaking of an isomorphism, here) with some *known* group. As the comments above suggest, the most likely candidate (based on your matrices' orders) is $S_3$, or (equivalently), the symmetry group $D_3$ of the equilateral triangle.

The latter group is most succinctly summed up as:

$D_3 = \langle a,b| a^3 = b^2 = e; ba = a^2b\rangle$.

With sufficient patience, one can show this determines a group of $6$ elements:

$D_3 = \{e,a,a^2,b,ab,a^2b\}$ and the rules $a^3 = b^2 = e$ and $ba = a^2b$ are sufficient to determine all $36$ entries in a multiplication table; for example:

$(ab)(a^2b) = a(ba)ab = a(a^2b)ab = (a^3)(bab) = e(bab) = (ba)b = (a^2b)b = a^2(b^2) = a^2e = a^2.$

Then it is a matter of finding some matrix $A$ of your $6$ we can map to $a$, and another $B$ that maps to $b$, and showing that the matrix multiplication of these two matrices satisfies our $3$ rules:

$A^3 = I\\B^2 = I\\BA = A^2B.$

If that is so, then the isomorphism we would get is:

$A^kB^l \mapsto a^kb^l$, and we would get a "parallel" multiplication table for your $6$ matrices corresponding to the multiplication table for $D_3$ (thus showing closure).

As pointed out above, we have for $A = \begin{bmatrix}0&1\\-1&-1\end{bmatrix}$:

$A^2 = \begin{bmatrix}0&1\\-1&-1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\-1&-1\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}-1&-1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}$, so that:

$A^3 = A^2A = \begin{bmatrix}-1&-1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\-1&-1\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix} = I.$

If we take $B = \begin{bmatrix}1&0\\-1&-1\end{bmatrix}$, we have:

$B^2 = \begin{bmatrix}1&0\\-1&-1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\-1&-1\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix} = I$, so there's $2$ out of $3$.

The third rule is tedious to verify, but here goes:

$BA = \begin{bmatrix}1&0\\-1&-1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\-1&-1\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}$, while:

$A^2B = \begin{bmatrix}-1&-1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\-1&-1\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}$,

so, indeed $BA = A^2B$.

Answer (score -1):

Multiply every matrix with every other matrix (that are 36 multiplications) and check if the resulting matrices are in your group.
That should proof closure.

Comment: I'm aware of that method However, that is extremely tedious and I can't image that is the indented way of going about it.

Comment: There is shorter proof (and that is probably what the OP is looking for). For example, find an element of order $3$, another of order $2$, and verify that the product is also in the group.