# $2\times 2$ Invertible Matrices in the Field Mod $2$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

Which $2\times 2$ matrices in the field mod $2$ are in $GL(2,\Bbb F)$ (i.e. have an invertible $2\times 2$ matrix in the same field which multiply to give you the identity matrix)? I could go case by case but was hoping there was a nicer approach.

Comment: Those with determinant $\neq0$ (that is, $\not\equiv0\pmod2$). There are six of them. An even better way would be to check when the rows (or columns) are linearly independent. No zero rows, no repeated rows, and you are done! Do you see why? (Hint: 1) not very many non-zero constants this time, 2) only two rows this time).

Comment: Oh, right. That makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: Do you know what $SL_2(F)$ means? If so, how would I approach that one?

Comment: If you want to see all six matrices, then look [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2033353/show-that-the-following-set-of-six-matrices-is-a-group?noredirect=1&lq=1), with $-1=1$. And $SL(2,F)$ is the subgroup of $GL(2,F)$ of those matrices with determinant $1$. In our case, hence, we have $GL(2,F)=SL(2,F)$.

Comment: Yeah I found the 6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A square matrix of any dimension with elements in *any* commutative, unital ring is invertible if its determinant is invertible. This is because for any square matrix $M$, you can define the [adjugate matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjugate_matrix) $\operatorname{adj}(M)$ with the property that
$$
\operatorname{adj}(M)\,M = M\,\operatorname{adj}(M) = \det(M)\cdot I
$$
which means that $M^{-1} = \det(M)^{-1}\operatorname{adj}(M)$, if the determinant is invertible.